# How to convert a group_concat, join, and union query into linq lambda?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

im pretty new to linq-lambda. I have a MySQL query that pulls the name of items in two tables union'd together. Then pull another column of the specialties that the items fall under.

my working query is this:

```
 Select
    p.title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(spec.categoryname) genre 
 From
    (SELECT FullName AS title, TypeId as typeid, Id as id FROM programs
        UNION
    SELECT FullName, TypeId, Id FROM products) 
        AS p
Inner join  specialtymembers mem  on (ItemType = p.typeid AND ItemId = p.id)
Inner join specialties spec on mem.Category = spec.id
 GROUP BY p.title
 ORDER BY p.title
```

now my problem is... that i have to somehow convert this into linq lambda. My attempt is this:

```
var allitems =
            _programContentService.Products.Select(r => r.FullName)
                .Union(_programContentService.Programs.Select(q => q.FullName))
                .Join(_programContentService.SpecialtyMembers, z => z.ItemType, q => q.ItemType,
                    (z, q) => new {z, q})
                .Join(_programContentService.Specialties, x => x.Id, z => z.Category,
                    (x, z) => new {x,z})
                    .Select(@t => new SelectListItem { Name = q.FillName.ToString(), Genre = "SOME HOW HAVE TO USE A LOOPING FEATURE??"  });
```

**UPDATE**:

```
var allitems = _programContentService
            .ProgramProductViews
            .Select(x => new {x.FullName, x.TypeId, x.Id})
            .Join(
                _programContentService.SpecialtyMembers,
                type => new {type.TypeId, type.Id},
                member => new {TypeId = member.ItemType, Id = member.ItemId},
                (type, member) => new {type.FullName, member.Category})
            .Join(
                _programContentService.Specialties,
                q => q.Category,
                specialty => specialty.Id,
                (q, specialty) => new { q.FullName, specialty.SpecialtyName })
            .GroupBy(x=>x.FullName)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.Key,
                     Text = String.Join(",", x.Select(q=>q.SpecialtyName))
                });
```

i have a feeling that I am close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will get you what you want.  It is untested, if you have issues let me know and I will work it out.

```
var allitems =
    _programContentService
    .Products
    .Select(x => new { x.FullName, x.TypeId, x.Id })
    .Union(
        _programContentService
        .Programs
        .Select(x => new { x.FullName, x.TypeId, x.Id }))
    .Join(
        _programContentService.SpecialtyMembers,
        type => new { type.TypeId, type.Id },
        member => new { TypeId = member.ItemType, Id = member.ItemId },
        (type, member) => new { type.FullName, member.Category })
    .Join(
        _programContentService.Specialties,
        x => x.Category,
        specialty => specialty.Id,
        (x, specialty) => new { x.FullName, specialty.CategoryName })
    .GroupBy(x => x.FullName)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem 
        { 
            Value = x.Key, 
            Text = String.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.CategoryName))
        });
```

Comment: nice!!!! i tested it out. all looks good except im getting some errors. On the second join, im getting the error: "the type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly"  and on .GroupBy, it cannot resolve symbol 'FullName'. then in new selectlistitem it cannot resolve 'Key'.

Comment: if i remove the second .Join it has no errors. so there much be something going on with the second join. hmmm.... i appreciate you help!

Comment: @NeoSketo - I have seen that before when the properties being joined are two different types.  What types are `SpecialtyMembers.Category` and `Specialties.Id`?  Is either one allowed to be null?

Comment: AH! you are right! SpecialtyMembers.Category was set as string when it should be int. I changed it and all checks out fine! THANK YOU! THANK YOU!

Comment: - Hey again! it looks like that last part name and genre can only be Text and Value. So i changed it to: Value = x.Key, Text = String,Join(",", x). But the main problem is the String.Join(",",x). Its giving me this error: InnerException {"The given expression 'new <>f__AnonymousTypeb`2(FullName = [x].FullName, SpecialtyName = [specialty].SpecialtyName)' does not contain the searched expression '[x]' in a nested NewExpression with member assignments or a MemberBindingExpression.\r\nParameter name: fullExpression"} System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Comment: The messege for the error is: Cannot create a LambdaExpression that retrieves the value of '[x]' from items with a structure of 'new <>f__AnonymousTypeb`2(FullName = [x].FullName, SpecialtyName = [specialty].SpecialtyName)'. The item expression does not contain the value or it is too complex.

Comment: is still giving me this error:  Message "Cannot create a LambdaExpression that retrieves the value of '[x]' from items with a structure of 'new <>f__AnonymousTypeb`2(FullName = [x].FullName, SpecialtyName = [specialty].SpecialtyName)'. The item expression does not contain the value or it is too complex." string

Comment: You need to add `System` to your using statements: `using System;` or call it like this `System.String.Join`.

Comment: yeah its added. i edited the query a little because im using NHibernate and unions isnt compatible. So i just created a view for the union. See my updated query in the question.

Comment: when i remove the .Groupby it shows all items as separate records for each specialty. which tells me the tables are populating correctly. So the only thing is that String.Join that holding it up. From what i get from that error, it seems like it doesn't know what to join? Or that it cant do a string join within a enumerable selected item list.

Comment: I am not positive but I suspect this may be an issue with nHibernate.  I don't know enough about nHibernate to say for sure.  I am curious to know what happens if you move `AsEnumerable` before `GroupBy` so that the grouping happens in memory rather having nHibernate handle the grouping.

Comment: Whew.  I did a quick search and it does look like nHibernate can have issues with `GroupBy`.  As a work around in the future I suggest returning your database results first (as we are doing with `AsEnumerable`) and doing the grouping on the resulting objects in memory.

Comment: yeah i agree! and well noted!! Thanks!